# Sass Dynamic Variable in Loop

Tags: css, sass

How to get `mixin argument` from `array variable` in a loop with **Sass**?
Example code is below:

```css
$colors: red green blue;
    $red-foo: 100px;
    $red-bar: 110px;
    $red-baz: 120px;
    $green-foo: 100px;
    $green-bar: 110px;
    $green-baz: 120px;
    $blue-foo: 100px;
    $blue-bar: 110px;
    $blue-baz: 120px;
    
    @mixin item($color-foo, $color-bar, $color-baz){
        width: $color-foo,;
        height: $color-bar;
        ...
    }
    
    @each $color in $colors {
        .class-#{$color}{
            @include item($color#{-foo}, $color#{-bar}, $color#{-baz})
        }
    }
```

Desired output is below:

```css
    .class-red{
        //variables
    }
    
    .class-green{
        //variables
    }
    
    .class-blue{
        //variables
    }
```

Also is there a way for shorthand of `$color-foo, $color-bar, $color-baz` like `@include item($color-shorthand)`? Maybe there could be a better solution for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want Sass Maps

```
$colors: (
    red: (
        foo: 100px,
        bar: 110px,
        baz: 110px
    ),
    green: (
        foo: 200px,
        bar: 210px,
        baz: 220px
    ),
    blue: (
        foo: 300px,
        bar: 310px,
        baz: 320px
    )
);

@mixin item ($color-foo, $color-bar, $color-baz) {
    width: $color-foo;
    height: $color-bar;
    padding: $color-baz;
}

@each $name, $value in $colors {
    .class-#{$name} {
        @include item(
            map-get($value, foo),
            map-get($value, bar),
            map-get($value, baz)
        );
    }
}
```